# Wie können wir den Themenbereich um geschlechtergerechte Sprache objektiv halten?

Tags: discussion

Fragen zum Thema geschlechtergerechte Sprache, generisches Maskulinum, u. Ä. ziehen unweigerlich Diskussionen und Kommentare dazu an, was denn nun richtig™ ist (siehe hierzu auch [diese Diskussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1336/2594). Diese sind nicht wirklich geeignet für diese Seite (außer vielleicht für den Chat). Häufig fehlt dabei dem Fragesteller schlicht das Hintergrundwissen, um zu erkennen, dass die Formulierung der Frage subjektive Antworten und Kommentare anzieht.

Möchten wir diese Probleme mit Regeln für solche Fragen angehen und wenn ja, mit welchen?

Stimmt für oder gegen Antworten, um Eure Zustimmung oder Ablehnung zum Vorgeschlagenen kundzutun.

---

The topic of gender-neutral language, the generic masculine, etc. almost inevitably attracts discussions and comments on what’s the right™ way (for example, see [this discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1336/2594)).
These are not suited for this site (except maybe for chat).
Often, the asker lacks the background knowledge to foresee that their way of asking attracts opinionated answers and comments.

Do we want rules for this sort of questions to address these issues and if yes, what shall they be?

Please vote on answers to indicate your agreement or disagreement with what is proposed.

Answer (score 14):

## Deutsch

Ich denke, dass wir bei solchen Fragen einen strikten Fokus auf [Deskriptivismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deskriptive_Linguistik) vorschreiben sollten, also die Beschreibung von Gebrauch, Regeln und Argumenten als Außenstehender.
Der Grund hierfür ist, dass es kaum umstritten ist, was Menschen tatsächlich nutzen oder wie sie argumentieren – im Gegensatz dazu, was genutzt werden sollte.

#### Fragen Stellen

Frage nach etwas wie:

- Was schreibt ein bestimmtes Paradigma für Gender in der Sprache in einem konkreten Fall vor?
- Inwieweit wird eine bestimmte Konstruktion genutzt?
- Welche Argumente führen die Befürworter einer bestimmten Vorschrift an?
- Welche verschiedenen Wege gibt es, eine bestimmte Konstruktion auszulegen?

Frage nicht nach etwas wie:

- Was soll ich nutzen? Was ist richtig?
- Wie wird eine bestimmte Konstruktion interpretiert oder gewertet?

Beachte auch: Wenn Du Dir vorstellen kannst, dass sich eine Frage mit »es ist umstritten« beantworten lässt, ist dies sehr wahrscheinlich der Fall.

Versieh die Frage mit folgender Warnung (oder ihrem englischen Äquivalent):

> *Lies bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor Du diese Frage beantwortest oder einen Kommentar schreibst.*

Zum Kopieren und Einfügen:

```
*Lies bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor Du diese Frage beantwortest oder einen Kommentar schreibst.*
```

#### Antworten und Kommentieren

- Beschreibe, was andere nutzen, empfehlen oder wie sie argumentieren.
- Stelle nicht Deine eigene Meinung dar und gib keine Empfehlungen zum Gebrauch.
  Empfehlungen aus relevanten Quellen wiederzugeben ist hingegen kein Problem.
  Idealerweise lässt Dein Post nicht erkennen, was Deine Meinung zum Thema Gender in der deutschen Sprache ist.
- Wenn Du antwortest, versuche die eigentliche Frage zu beantworten.
- [Zweckentfremde Kommentare nicht](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), sprich, kommentiere vorwiegend um einen Beitrag zu verbessern.
  Lass nicht einfach Beispielsätze ohne Erklärung im Raum stehen.

#### (Community)moderation

- Wenn möglich, versuche eine Frage dahingehend zu ändern, dass sie die obigen Regeln befolgt.
  Zögere insbesondere nicht, subjektive Teilfragen zu entfernen und obige Warnung einzufügen.
  Sollte dies nicht möglich sein, stimme dafür, die Frage als *primarily opinion-based* zu schließen.
- Wenn eine Antwort persönliche Meinungen und Empfehlungen enthält, entferne sie oder bitte den Verfasser, dies zu tun.
  Sollte danach nichts übrig bleiben, stimme dafür, die Antwort zu löschen (Flagge oder Löschstimme).
- Flagge Kommentare, die obige Regeln nicht befolgen, als *no longer needed.*

## English

I think that, for such questions, we should impose a clear focus on [descriptvism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description), i.e., the description of usage, rules, and rationales from an outside point of view.
The rationale for this is that there is little dispute as to what people actually use or how they argue – in contrast to what should be used.

#### Asking

Ask for something like:

- What does a given paradigm for gender and language recommend in a specific situation?
- To what extent is a certain construction actually used?
- What is the rationale behind a given recommendation of usage?
- What are all possible ways to understand a given construction?

Do not ask something like:

- What should one use? What is correct?
- How will a certain choice of usage be interpreted or judged?

Also, be aware that if you can imagine that the answer to your question is “there is no consensus”, it almost certainly is.

Equip your question with the following boilerplate warning (or the German equivalent):

> *Before you answer or comment on this question, please read [our guidelines for questions on gender-neutral language and similar](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340).*

For copying and pasting:

```
*Before you answer or comment on this question, please read [our guidelines for questions on gender-neutral language and similar](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340).*
```

#### Answering and Commenting

- Describe what others use, suggest, how they argue, etc.
- Do not state your opinion or make recommendations on what to use; however, quoting recommendations of relevant sources is fine.
  Ideally, it should not be possible to deduce your opinion on gendered language from your post.
- If you are answering, stick to the question.
- If you are commenting, stick to the [intended purposes](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) of comments, in particular improving the post.
  Do not just drop example sentences or similar without any explanation.

#### (Community) Moderating

- If you can edit a question to comply with the above rules, do so.
  In particular, do not hesitate to remove opinionated subquestions and add the boilerplate.
  If this cannot be done, flag or vote to close the question as *primarily opinion-based.*
- If an answer contains personal recommendations or opinions on the topic, edit them out or ask the author to do this.
  If nothing would be left after this, flag the answer for deletion and vote to delete it (if you have the reputation, or in review).
- Flag comments not adhering to the above rules as *no longer needed.*

Comment: Im deutschen Teil solltest Du den Begriff [geschlechtergerechte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) dem schwammigen Begriff *Gender* vorziehen. Likewise in the English part where [gender-neutral language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_language) is the corresponding term. This would also make the title clearer (what is meant by *social gender* anyway...?). Ansonst ganz gut :)

Comment: Ich habe den Begriff *geschlechtergerechte Sprache* gezielt vermieden, weil das Problem ja auch bei Fragen über vermeintlich nicht geschlechtergerechte Sprache auftritt. *Gender* im Deutschen und *social gender* im Englischen nutze ich ebenfalls gezielt, um eine Verwechslung mit dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht zu vermeiden. Wenn das verwirrt, bin ich aber offen für Vorschläge.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_construction_of_gender - könnte zu Mißverständnissen führen. Mit dem englischen [Gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender) meint man so gut wie nie die grammatische (wozu auch?), und das deutsche Lehnwort [Gender](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender) ist wieder mehrdeutig... Deshalb mein Vorschlag, die jeweils etablierten Begriffe zu nehmen.

Comment: Hmm, ich versuche es mal mit den üblichen Begriffen plus *u. Ä.* Das ist zwar auch prinzipiell schwammig, aber es sollte relativ klar sein, um was es geht.

Comment: I think this is the most valid approach, but find it difficult to imagine how we handle something that starts from some naive question like "How can 'der Hund' be male?" and evolve from there. The original questioner will probably have difficulties to  understand what discussion he generated around his question...

Comment: @tofro: It depends on the details. If such a question focusses on understanding grammatical gender, there is hopefully no reason to do anything. If it is indeed touching the topics of gender-equal language and similar, the aforementioned warning can hopefully prevent such a discussion.

Comment: Mir entgeht grade ein bisschen, was denn der Unterschied zwischen *Stelle nicht Deine eigene Meinung dar* und *Beschreibe, was andere ..., empfehlen oder wie sie argumentieren* sein könnte - Beides ist definitiv **opinionated**, nur zweiteres nicht notwendigerweise meine Meinung. Ist "opinion-based" erlaubt, wenn man die Meinung nur zitiert? Das halte ich, mit Verlaub, für Unsinn.

Comment: @tofro: Wenn jemand einfach eine Position hinschreibt, wird dies als Empfehlung aufgefasst bzw. als Aussage darüber was richtig™ ist und es führt dazu, dass als Abstimmung darüber genutzt werden. Das ist die Meinungslastigkeit, die ich vermeiden möchte. Eine Beschreibung der Meinung anderer kann objektiv richtig oder falsch sein und kann Motivationen gut erklären oder nicht. »Das generische Maskulinum ist falsch weil …« ist eine persönliche Meinung; »X hält das generische Maskulinum für falsch, weil …« nicht. Letzteres kann ein Verfechter des generischen Maskulinums hochstimmen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "tofro hält das generische Maskulinum für falsch, weil..." ist dann keine persönliche Meinung? Oder gar "Viele sind der Meinung, das generische Maskulinum sei falsch..." (Einfach mal behaupten...) Nur deswegen, weil *Meiner* und *Schreiber* nicht derselbe sind? Sorry, das halte ich immer noch für Unsinn.. **SE is about *facts***. Das Problem ist, dass es zum Thema fast keine greifbaren *Fakten*, sondern größtenteils *Meinungen* gibt. Es sollte keine erlaubt sein - keine eigene und auch keine zitierte.

Comment: @tofro: "tofro hält das generische Maskulinum für falsch, weil..." ist dann keine persönliche Meinung? Wenn Tofro eine relevante Quelle ist, nein. Dass z. B. eine Menge von Leuten eine Meinung vertritt, kann ein Fakt sein bzw. es ist zumindest hinreichend faktisch für die Ansprüche dieser Seite. Wenn ich wirklich gründlich sein möchte, kann ich es z. B. durch Umfragen erfassen. — Mal anders angegangen: »So wird die Sprache verwendet.« oder »Gruppe X schlägt vor, dass die Sprache so verwendet werden sollte.« sind in Ordnung. »So sollte die Sprache verwendet werden.« ist nicht in Ordnung.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Wenn du das meinst (wobei ich dir grundsätzlich beipflichten würde), solltest du es auch hinschreiben. Zwei Bullet-Points  hintereinander, die nacheinander sagen "Schreibe nicht deine Meinung" und "Schreibe die Meinung von Anderen" geben das eindeutig nicht wieder.

Answer (score 3):

Was war hier nochmal das eigentliche Problem?

Fragen, Frageninhalt? Oder unerwünschtes Nutzerverhalten?
Weit verbreitetes Nutzerverhalten?

Man kann das schon beobachten bei der derzeitigen Anwendung der Vorschläge für CloseVotes: ist nichts weiter als die Rechtfertigung zur Willkür. Es fehlt ein Regelsatz und Erklärungen dazu. Aber dieser lässt sich wohl auch gar nicht zufriedenstellend für diesen SE formulieren?

Primarily Opinion Based hat bei zu vielen Themen hier schlicht keine Berechtigung und die Verwendung ist offensichtlich oft idiotisch, keinesfalls jedoch uniform und gerecht. Ebenso die kürzlich gegebene Vorgabe, 'alles politische, subjektive zu entfernen und religiöse Aspekte zu vermeiden.'

Anders gefragt, sind die folgenden Fragen und Antworten frei von politischen Implikationen und *nicht* primarily opinion based (POB)?

- [What is the neutral and the male word for 'Hausfrau'?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28259/what-is-the-neutral-and-the-male-word-for-hausfrau)
- [Is it appropriate to use the Binnen-I in a formal context (such as a job application cover letter)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44617/is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-binnen-i-in-a-formal-context-such-as-a-job-applica)
- [Wie könnte man “spouse” gender-neutral übersetzen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/wie-k%C3%B6nnte-man-spouse-gender-neutral-%C3%BCbersetzen)

Der gesamte tag gender-neutrality ist voll von POB, wie könnte er anders sein? Und der tag an sich ist auch schon Teil der politischen Debatte. Wie soll es nur möglich sein, da 'die Politik' oder 'Subjektivität' herauszuhalten?

Der ganze Kladderadatsch hier liegt nicht begründet in der unauflöslichen Verquickung von Subjektivität und Intersubjektivität von Sprache. Ursächlich ist auch nicht die technische Limitiertheit des Systems. Und es sind nicht nur solche (gender) Fragen. Man sieht das hier dauernd.

Was ist 'best word for', 'schreibt man', 'sollte man', 'korrekte Anrede', etc pp.

Fast alle single-word-requests fallen ebenfalls zwangsläufig unter opinion based; und prompt hagelt's auch regelhaft Nö-Kommentare.

**Das Problem ist der missionarische und oft repetitive Dogmatismus einiger User hier.**

"Neinneinein" "Das ist falsch" ist wohl der häufigste Typ von Kommentar hier. Subjektivität in Antworten hat ihren Platz, wenn sie beschrieben, begründet und referenziert wird erst recht. Die elende Rechthaberei in den Kommentaren hingegen nicht.

Weder das technische System, noch die Fragen sind 'das Problem'. Weder Subjektivität noch politischer Inhalt sind das Problem, und beides ist der ganzen Seitenthematik *inhärent!*

Das ist keine Ablehnung zu Wrzlprmfts nudging [Vorschläge oben](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1341/29694), sondern eine notwendige Ergänzung.

Aber wenn das eben kritisierte Nutzerverhalten "sein muss": schnelleres move2chat und die zwanghaften "my-opinion is better than yours" Kommentare löschen.

Also:

- Was hier auf Meta zu fehlen scheint: eine ausführlichere Erläuterung was POB bzgl Sprache sein soll (da ein mindestens zweistelliger Prozentsatz der vorhandenen non-closed Fragen unter die gegenwärtige Formulierung fallen müsste). Wie ganz oben andeutet wäre das aber nur ein buntes Pflaster auf eine klaffende Wunde. Ich plädiere für eine vollständige Neuformulierung oder gar Abschaffung dieser Dosenbegründung (pre-canned close-reason).
- Es reicht nicht aus, und wäre zum Teil kontraproduktiv, nur den Fragenden und den Text einer Frage hin zu 'unkontrovers' zu modifizieren. Wenn das Licht die Mücken anzieht, sitzt man noch lange nicht gern im Dunkeln, weil die Mücken so lästig sind. Man nehme weniger verlockendes Licht (Wrzlprmft nudging) oder halte die Biester fern (move & delete).

Comment: *Was war hier nochmal das eigentliche Problem?* – Derartige Fragen haben problematisches Nutzerverhalten hervorgerufen und teilweise wurden die Fragesteller mehr verwirrt als alles andere. — Zum Rest: Das ist sehr viel Holz, von dem vieles nichts mit diesem konkreten Problem zu tun hat. Zumindest die Frage, ob wir ähnliche Regelung (sprich expliziten Deskriptivismus) auch für andere Kategorien benötigen, würde ich getrennt stellen.

Comment: Von zwei Komponenten wird nur eine angegangen, als ob es exklusive Kausalbeziehung wär, aber da Aspekt B (Nutzerverhalten) auch andernorts Probleme bereitet sollte man wenigsten B bei diesem Problem ebenfalls bearbeiten, und die tatsächlichen Ursachen analysieren, um eine bigger picture Lösung erarbeiten zu können. Die SO-Brogrammer Regeln in derzeitiger Formulierung und Konzeptionalisierung weisen da IMO systematische Schwächen für unseren SE auf. Diese forlorn hope-Fahne möcht ich aber nicht durch MetaSE tragen, ohne wenigstens mehr Zustimmung für die Analyse hier drüber zu haben.

Answer (score 2):

Die Apologeten der sogenannten Gendergerechten oder Geschlechtergerechten Sprache versuchen oft, die bestehende Sprache als fraglos ungerecht darzustellen. Diese politische Unterstellung muss aber thematisiert werden. Man kann nicht so tun, als gäbe es diese Bestrebungen nicht, als sei das keine politisch motivierte Kampagne, die sprachwissenschaftlichen Erkenntnissen zuwiderläuft.

Man muss ja erklären, wieso die Leute in ihrem Alltag dieser Manipulation so oft begegnen.

Die Fehleinschätzung ist ja auch keine Randerscheinung.

Man kann die Leser nur mit den Argumenten pro und kontra konfrontieren, und diese sich ihre eigene Meinung bilden lassen.

Es beginnt ja schon mit dem Begriff *Gendergerechte Sprache*. Gerechtigkeit gegenüber Artikeln und Personalpronomen will man hoffentlich noch nicht walten lassen, also bezieht sich Gender auf den soziologischen Begriff.

Dieser meint, in Abgrenzung zu Geschlecht, die Geschlechtsrolle. Dahinter steht die Vermutung, dass sich das biologische Geschlecht von der Rolle analytisch trennen ließe. `*`

So gesehen ist die überlieferte Sprache also nicht ungerecht gegen Personen, die biologisch Frauen sind, sondern gegen Personen, die die Frauenrolle, besser gesagt eine Frauenrolle verkörpern, ausfüllen, sich mit einer solchen identifizieren.

Zu 99% sehen sich ja biologische Frauen selbst als Frauen und umgekehrt dürften 99% derer, die als Frauen gesehen werden, auch biologisch gesehen solche sein. Das macht es schon schwierig, Definitives über die Ausnahmen zusammenzutragen.

Wenn die Frauenrolle darin bestünde, unterdrückt zu sein, dann wäre eine geschlechtsrollengerechte Sprache ja eine, die diese Unterdrückung zementiert. Feministinnen müssten dann die letzten sein, die sich für eine solche Sprache einsetzen. Feministinnen würden sich ja gerade nicht mit ihrer Rolle identifizieren.

Aber die intensive Beschäftigung mit dem Thema ist den meisten zu anstrengend und so fast man rasch eine Meinung, die Meinung der persönlich Peergroup, oh Wunder, und gibt sich mit der nächstbesten Erklärung zufrieden.

Wer sich mit dem Thema nicht tiefer befassen will, der soll diese Diskussionen eben meiden. Aber anderen vorzuschreiben, dass das Thema tabu zu sein hat, ist ein Rückfall in die Vormoderne.

Dass das Thema umstritten ist und von Emotionen begleitet, liegt am Thema und der gesellschaftlichen Realität. Wem's in der Küche zu heiß ist, der soll eben draußen bleiben.

Dieser Vorstoß hier riecht mir sehr danach, unter dem Deckmantel der Neutralität die Realität zu leugnen, wie bei den Kreationisten, die ihre Auffassung von der Schöpfung als legitime Alternative zur Evolution verbreitet sehen wollen.

Die Wahrheit verträgt keine Aufpasser.

*) Natürlich gibt es soziale Rollen. Man muss kein Ethnologe oder Geschichtswissenschaftler sein, um zu sehen, dass sich Männer und Frauen im Ausland anders kleiden als hierzulande, und dass es auch hierzulande vor 20, 50, 500 Jahren anders aussah, was etwa die Kleidung betrifft, die Berufswahl, das Verhalten. Wovon Ethnologen aber noch nicht berichtet haben, das sind Gesellschaften ohne Geschlechtsrollen.

Umgekehrt sieht man aber, dass Sprachen ohne grammatikalisches Geschlecht oder eine solche, die fast ohne ein solches auskommt, wie das Englische, überhaupt keinen Einfluss auf die Rollenausgestaltung hat. Ein Deutschmuttersprachler hat in den USA keine Schwierigkeiten, die dortigen Rollenmuster und Geschlechtsverhältnisse zu begreifen und umgekehrt stolpern Engländer in Deutschland nur über die Sprache aber auch nicht über die Geschlechterverhältnisse.

Die Idee, mit einer Sprachreform etwas fundamental zu verändern, ist also empirisch schlecht aufrechtzuerhalten. Dahinter steckt der alte Wunschglauben, mit magischen Zauberformeln die Welt zu bannen und Dreck in Gold verwandeln zu können.

Comment: [Diskussion in den Chat verschoben, da sie sonst zu unübersichtlich wird](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74290/discussion-on-answer-by-user-unknown-wie-konnen-wir-den-themenbereich-um-geschle).

Comment: Wenn auch interessant als grundsätzlicher Beitrag zur Genderproblemtaik, so doch völlig am Metathema der Frage vorbei. Deshalb mein Downvote hier.

Comment: @Thomas Finde ich schwierig, immerhin stecken hier ja auch Antworten auf die Frage mitdrinnen, und das macht es schwierig zischen Downvote für die verstreuten Empfehlungen und Downvote für die Themenverfehlung zu unterscheiden. Kräftiger Edit wäre wahrscheinlich die Lösung.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft (als Moderator) Hmm, ich wollte diesen Edit nur vorschlagen. Seit wann kann ich denn einfach so drüberfahren? Und wie mache ich das richtig?

Comment: @sgf: [Seit Du mehr als 1000 Erfahrung hast.](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) So etwas wie Änderungen nur dem Autor vorschlagen gibt es auf SE grundsätzlich nicht. Schreibe bei so umfassenden Änderungen lieber stattdessen eine neue Antwort.

Comment: @sgf Ich bin mit Downvotes auf der Hauptseite viel zurückhaltender, aber im Meta kann man das schon mal machen. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas Ja, aber gerade im Meta bedeutet ein Downvote ja auch, dass du dich der Meinung des Posters nicht anschließt, nicht nur, dass der Post nicht den formalen Anforderungen entspricht.

Comment: @sgf, Ich würde auch abraten des Original zu editieren, mache am besten einen Extrakt mit deinen Interpretationen und verwende so viel Text wie du magst mit einem kleinen Disclaimer am Anfang.

Comment: Hier https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/deklination/gender-nubling-lobin-sueddeutsche.php ist ein weiterer Beitrag zum Thema auf belleslettres, der einmal mehr unterstreicht, wie unwissenschaftlich die feministische Sprachkritik ist.

Comment: *Wer sich mit dem Thema nicht tiefer befassen will, der soll diese Diskussionen eben meiden. Aber anderen vorzuschreiben, dass das Thema tabu zu sein hat, ist ein Rückfall in die Vormoderne.* ... *Die Wahrheit verträgt keine Aufpasser.* Richtig™. Das +1 aber vor allem dafür: *Dieser Vorstoß hier riecht mir sehr danach, unter dem Deckmantel der Neutralität die Realität zu leugnen.*

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt meines Erachtens nur die Möglichkeit des Hinweisens auf die Ungeklärtheit dieser Problematik, also daß eine Frage ggf. Opinion Based ist.

So schön der Deskriptivismus erscheinen mag, setzt er doch wissenschafltich anerkannte (objektive) Fakten voraus, die es einfach in diesem Themenbereich (noch) nicht gibt. Jeder noch so gut gemeinte Versuch einer objektiven Betrachtung wird durch Alternativen und andere Meinungen konterkariert werden. Dazu ist das Thema einfach zu heiß.
Von daher halte ich das Bemühen um eine objektive Behandlung für utopisch.

Allerdings möchte ich mit meinem Skeptizismus keine derartigen Fragen verbannt wissen. Ggf. gibt es ja die Möglichkeit solche Fragen mit einer Flagge zu versehen, die auf das Opinion Biasing hinweisen, aber vlt. dennoch qualitativ hochwertige Antworten provozieren.

Comment: Und ich werte diesen Beitrag ab, weil er sich dafür stark macht, bestimmte Themen als heikel auszuzeichnen, was eben alles andere als eine neutrale Haltung zum Thema ist.

Comment: *So schön der Deskriptivismus erscheinen mag, setzt er doch wissenschafltich anerkannte (objektive) Fakten voraus* – Da hast Du Deskriptivismus falsch verstanden. Deskriptivismus ist zunächst einmal eine Art der Beschreibung und die meisten Antworten auf dieser Seite können ohne Probleme deskriptivistisch formuliert werden, auch wenn sie nicht wissenschaftlich untermauert sind. Jedes Wörterbuch versucht deskriptivistisch zu sein, ohne das jetzt für jeden Eintrag eine Studie dazu durchgeführt wird, wie die Sprecherschaft einer Sprache dieses Wort versteht.

Comment: Natürlich kann niemand wissenschaftlich belegen, welches Paradigma für Gender und Sprache das beste ist. Man kann aber sehr wohl beschreiben, was Menschen nutzen oder wie sie argumentieren. Natürlich kann diese Beschreibung wiederum richtig oder falsch sein, aber das kann man relativ friedlich klären.

Comment: Ich verstehe, vlt. habe ich den Deskriptivismus etwas überbewertet, aber dennoch benötigt er eine gewisse objektive Basis ob wissenschaftlich oder nicht, die ich allerdings bei diesem Thema einfach nicht erkennen kann. Es wird immer kontrovers einhergehen, wie selbst hier zu sehen. Aber gerade auch das ruft natürlich nach einem eingreifenden Regularium, wenn ich auch meine Zweifel der Fruchtbarkeit habe.

Comment: @Thomas: *aber dennoch benötigt er eine gewisse objektive Basis […], die ich allerdings bei diesem Thema einfach nicht erkennen kann.* – klar. Allerdings ist die Beschreibung der Meinungen anderer u. Ä. schon deutlich objektiver und weniger umstritten als die Frage, was denn nun die richtige Meinung sei. Zum Beispiel ist das Konfliktpotenzial bei einer Aussage wie »Einige Menschen denken, dass generisch maskuline Formen Frauen nicht beinhalten.« deutlich geringer als bei »Das generische Maskulinum beinhaltet Frauen nicht.« Die erste Aussage bestreitet nämlich kaum jemand.